# Freeform, Entering a value and inserting the value in another field in same form

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to use the value that a user inputs into another input on the same form on submit.

The idea is that they input their phone number, in the phone_number field and on submit of the form it prepends phone_number infront of some other text in a seperate field on the same form.

So end result is : 07231923738(prepended text)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do with Javascript, as long as you explicitly target the fields by name or ID.